# Ubuntu 14.04 : new Graphic card slower boot

Tags: boot, graphics-card, bios, ubuntu-14.04

I installed a GeForce GTX 650 on my desktop but since then when my PC boots it stays on the BIOS approximately 30 seconds. Before it was only 2 seconds and I don't know why. Maybe I read that I need to update my BIOS, but I don't know how, and it seems complicated. How to remove the boot delay?

Answer (score 2):

The extra time is the time required to run the new graphics card's firmware intitialization routines.

Comment: No it's been one month and it's still doing the same thing :/

Comment: The initialization routines have to run every time the system boots. It will be the same a year from now.

Comment: So, it's normal to wait 30 sec... ? Or Can I do something ?

Comment: For that card? It would appear so. Different cards may have different load times / timeout values. But it is normal for a boot to take longer if you've added new hardware.